# Pass array to next page in angular after user clicks button

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass data to another page in angular however I wish to do so without exposing the data in the url.

This is my data set that I want to transfer

```
[
  {
    "deliveryAddress": "a.a@a.com",
    "accountNumber": "1234",
    "deliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
    "renderSucceeded": true,
    "renderError": null
  },
  {
    "deliveryAddress": "b.b@b.com",
    "accountNumber": "5678",
    "deliveryChannel": "EMAIL",
    "renderSucceeded": true,
    "renderError": null
  }
]
```

This is my routing array. I want to navigate to page2.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'page1', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'page1', component:  AppComponent},
  { path: 'page2', component: page2Component }
];
```

Comment: use service for data sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store this data in any service and you can use that service to get that data.
address.service.ts

```
import
{
    Injectable
}
from '@angular/core';
@Injectable(
{
    providedIn: "root"
})
export class AddressService
{
    addresses: any;
    constructor()
    {}
    doAnyThing()
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

page1.component.ts

```
export class Page1Component
{
    constructor(private addressesService: AddressesService)
    {}
    onUserClick()
    {
        this.addressesService.addresses = this.addresses;
    }
}
```

page2.component.ts

```
export class Page2Component
{
    constructor(private addressesService: AddressesService)
    {}
    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.addresses = this.addressesService.addresses;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I pass the data from page1 in the service?

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic | Nav Params**:

1st Page

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

onClick() {
  let yourArray = ["hellow from the other side"]
  this.navCtrl.push(SecondPage, yourArray)
}
```

2nd Page

```
constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
  console.log(this.navParams.data)
}
```

---

**Web | Route Params**

Currently Angular does not provide a way of passing additional data with `router.navigate`.
There are many use cases for this, described in related issues which were unjustly closed without fulfilment.

There is also a workaround solution for this as well.
Install

```
npm install angular2-navigate-with-data -save
```

Initialise this in your app module.

```
import "angular2-navigate-with-data";
```

Now, 1st Page

```
constructor (
        private router: Router
    ){}

    public redirect()
    {
        this.router.navigateByData({
            url: ["/PageTwo"],
            data: [1,2,3,4,5], //data - <any> type
            //extras: {} - <NavigationExtras> type, optional parameter
        });
    }
```

Second Page,

```
constructor (
        private router: Router
    ){}

    public ngOnInit()
    {
        console.log(this.router.getNavigatedData()); //output [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
```

I hope this works. Thanks

Comment: Is NavController not fo Ionic only?

Comment: Yes sorry, it is limited to Ionic only. Check my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typescript and javascript to do that. When clicking the button you write a method in .ts

Example:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
onClick(){
   let navigationParameters = [YOUR ARRAY];
   this.router.navigate(['/THE PAGE YOU WANT TO NAVIGATE'],navigationParameters);
}
```